# Probability inequality involving symmetrized random variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, symmetry

**Definition of symmetrized random variable**
[image: symm]

**The theorem that I want to prove :**
[image]

**Source : Rohatgi, Saleh (3rd edition), p.$121$**

Part $(a)$ is an easy consequence of triangle inequality. I'm having trouble with part $(b)$. The right-hand side of the inequality is estimated as follows.

$$P\left\{\left|X\right|>a+\epsilon\right\}=P\left\{X<-a-\epsilon\right\}+P\left\{X>a+\epsilon\right\} \leq P\left\{X \leq -a\right\}+P\left\{X \geq a\right\} \leq 2(1-p) \tag{1}$$

Thus, if we can show that $P\left\{\left|X^s\right| \geq \epsilon\right\} \geq 2(1-p)$, then we are done. This is where I'm stuck. Is it possible to show this? Or are we loosing too much in $(1)$? Also, I'd be grateful if anyone can provide me a direct solution/hint. Thank you.

Comment: You are loosing too much in (1); nothing is known about the value of $p$ except that $0<p<1$. If $p<1/2$ then $2(1-p)>1$ so you cannot show that $P\{|X^{s}| \geq \epsilon\} \geq 2(1-p)$.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638117/probability-inequality-via-symmetrization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is not hard to show $$\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X^s\rvert \geq \varepsilon\} \geq \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X\rvert > a+\varepsilon\}\cdot p\,.\tag{$\dagger$}$$
Indeed, for $a,p$ as in the statement and any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
$$
\{ \lvert X\rvert > a+\varepsilon \} = 
\{ X > a+\varepsilon \}\cup \{ X < -(a+\varepsilon) \}
$$
and
$$
\left(\{ X > a+\varepsilon\}\cap \{ X' \leq a \}\right)\cup \left(\{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\}\cap \{ X' \geq -a \}\right) \subseteq \{ \lvert X-X'\rvert \geq \varepsilon\}\,.
$$
Therefore, since $\mathbb{P}\{ X' \leq a \} \geq p$ and $\mathbb{P}\{ X' \geq -a \} \geq p$ by assumption, we get *(here I'll detail a lot)*
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X^s\rvert \geq \varepsilon\}
&= \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X-X'\rvert \geq \varepsilon\}
\geq \mathbb{P}\left( \left(\{ X > a+\varepsilon\}\cap \{ X' \leq a \}\right)\cup \left(\{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\}\cap \{ X' \geq -a \}\right) \right)\\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(\{ X > a+\varepsilon\}\cap \{ X' \leq a \}\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(\{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\}\cap \{ X' \geq -a \}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\{ X > a+\varepsilon\} \mathbb{P}\{ X' \leq a \} + \mathbb{P}\left(\{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\} \mathbb{P}\{ X' \geq -a \}\right) \\
&\geq \mathbb{P}\{ X > a+\varepsilon\} \cdot p + \mathbb{P}\{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\} \cdot p \\
&= p\cdot \mathbb{P}\{ X > a+\varepsilon\} \cup \{ X < -(a+\varepsilon)\}\\
&= p\cdot  \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > a+\varepsilon \}\,.
\end{align}
$$

---

Without the extra $p$, however, the result is simply **false** *(the fact that the end inequality does not depend on $p$ is a big clue)*. As a counter example, take $X$ to be a Rademacher r.v., i.e. uniform on $\{-1,1\}$; then, for $a=0$ and $p=1/2$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X\geq 0\} = 1-p, \qquad \mathbb{P}\{X\leq 0\} = 1-p
$$
(so a fortiori the inequalities hold). Now, the symmetrized r.v. $X^s$ satisfies
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X^s=0\} = \frac{1}{2},\qquad \mathbb{P}\{X^s=2\} =\mathbb{P}\{X^s=-2\} = \frac{1}{4}
$$
so, for any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, 
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X^s\rvert \geq \varepsilon\} = \frac{1}{2} = p\cdot 1 = p\cdot \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X\rvert > \varepsilon\}\,.
$$